# Slick Slider ng-click is not clickable when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, slick.js

Using slick slider I am trying to put ng-click on a button inside a slick element but firing the click event does not call the function defined in the ng-click directive.

```
<slick dots="true" 
       infinite="true" 
       speed="300" 
       slides-to-show="4" 
       touch-move="false" 
       slides-to-scroll="1" 
       variable-width="false" 
       class="slider slick-slider" 
       responsive="plans_slick_responsive">
    <div class="list-item" ng-repeat="plan in plans">
        <button class="btn slick-btn select-plan" 
                ng-click="select_plan(plan)" 
                ng-model="plan">
            <span>Select Plan</span>
        </button>
    </div>            
</slick>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are triggering the click event programatically use should use something like:

```
    angular.element('#buttonID').triggerHandler('click');
```

In order to apply it to your code, you must add the id property to your button, resulting something like:

```
<slick dots="true" 
   infinite="true" 
   speed="300" 
   slides-to-show="4" 
   touch-move="false" 
   slides-to-scroll="1" 
   variable-width="false" 
   class="slider slick-slider" 
   responsive="plans_slick_responsive">
<div class="list-item" ng-repeat="plan in plans">
    <button class="btn slick-btn select-plan" 
            ng-click="select_plan(plan)" 
            id="buttonID" 
            ng-model="plan">
        <span>Select Plan</span>
    </button>
</div>
```